# SQLDeveloper keeps crashing when compiling packages in Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, macos, virtualbox, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have Oracle SQLDeveloper installed on a Mac. Versions are listed below:

> SQL Developer: Version 19.1.0.094, Build 094.2042
>
> Mac: macOS Mojave 10.14.6 (18G1012)
>
> Java: Java 8 Update 231

I have an Oracle database installed in a Virtual Box running Linux. I have been connecting to this database through SQLDeveloper and creating and editing packages successfully for the past couple of months. However, this week SQLDeveloper has started crashing/hanging when I try to compile packages. I have not been able to identify any specific patterns so far.

I open SQLDeveloper and start making changes to a package and the first couple of compilations go through fine. Then suddenly when I issue a Compile command, the application hangs. I can continue using the Mac, but cannot click anywhere on the SQLDeveloper.

I tried opening a new instance of SQLDeveloper (by copying the SQLDeverloper icon in Applications). Then I queried v$session and noticed that the session that was compiling the package is showing as 'INACTIVE'.

Has anyone faced these sort of issues before and/or know any way around this?

Comment: Also look at the column `V$SESSION.BLOCKING_SESSION` - if someone else is using the package in a SQL statement you won't be able to compile it until they're done.

Comment: Are you sure that the package isn't in use? This is precisely the behavior I'd expect if you try to compile a package that is in use in the database. **Eventually** you'll get a timeout error and your session will free up, but it often takes several minutes.

Comment: @JonHeller, the package is not being used by any other session, unfortunately. This seems to be something else that I have never seen before. When I use SQLDeveloper within VirtualBox, it seems to be stable. I think this might have something to do with the connection from the sqldeveloper in the host machine to the database in VirtualBox. Is there any setting or configuration I can check to make sure this is set to optimal values?

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica- there's no other session using the package. I checked the v$session row for the compilation and I found this value in the Event column "SQL*Net break/reset to client". Reading about this error message, it sounds like the database is trying to reset the connection with the client probably? And this happened during compilation. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?